# How do you print x number of lines at a time

Tags: java, events, printing

I have a program that prints the instance variables of objects stored in an arraylist.
I want to add a feature to this program so it only prints the instance variables for first 10 objects, then ask the user to press enter to continue, then continues with the next 10 objects and so on.

Here is an example of how the printing loop looks without the function i'm asking for:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
  {
    System.out.println(myList.get(i).getName();
  }
```

The "Press enter to continue" part is easy enough:

```
import java.util.*;
...
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.nextLine()
```

but how do i create a conditional loop that stops after 10 prints and then resumes after the "Press enter to continue" event??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with my own approach.
I wish i could credit everyone with an answer-tick as my suggestion is a combination of them all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{
  if(i % 10 == 0 && i != 0){
    System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
    input.nextLine();
  }
  System.out.println(myList.get(i).getName());
}
```

Putting the printing outside the if statement makes more sense.
Now it properly prints 10 statements the first time instead of 11.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
  {
    System.out.println(myList.get(i).getName();
    if(i % 10 == 0){
         input.nextLine()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `System.in.read()`, It reads a character and hence when the user presses any key, it continues.

> Other wise waits for the user to input.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
  {
    System.out.println(myList.get(i).getName();
    if(i % 10 == 0){
         System.out.println("Press any key to continue!");
         char ch = (char) System.in.read();
    }
  }
```

Comment: `if(i % 10 == 0 && i != 0)` would be a good idea to have it display the first 10 results without asking.

Comment: Even `read()` will not continue as soon as a key is pressed.. It will wait for user to press enter **(and them mess up stuff in the next iterations)**.

Comment: @UmaKanth that's genius! thanks! However, i can't get the "any key" portion to work. `char ch = (char) System.in.read();` still requires me to press enter for it to register (is this OS dependent? I'm on Win 7 using cmd for refrence)

Comment: @dly Thanks, that was a great addition :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
for(int index = 0; i <myList.size(); i++){

         /*check if it has printed 10 times first or else, it'll be printed 11 times first*/
         if( i % 10 == 0 && i!=0 ){
             System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
             //Prompt the user of course... 
             input.nextLine();
         }
         System.out.println(myList.get(i).getName());
}
```

as commented in the code above, you need to check if it is printed 10 times first. @bmscomp's code might have a bug if it has more than 10 entries.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum :) My code does indeed print 11 entries on the first iteration. Not entirely sure how to fix it though, will have to try some things.

Comment: You're welcome and please don't forget to click the check button if it has answered your question so that the future visitors of this question know the answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can have a better idea on what to be done on receiving user input.
Please try following:-
`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetInputFromUser {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a;
    float b;
    String s;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered string " + s);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You entered integer " + a);

    System.out.println("Enter a float");
    b = in.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("You entered float " + b);
}
}
```

Comment: why negative? may be its not the correct but this is what required here.